# Go HTTP RoundTripper: Preventing Connection Reuse Based on Response

Tags: http, go, go-http

I have a use case where I want to use an HTTP client in Go with pooled connections (connection re-use), but with the special case where a connection is intentionally closed (not allowed for re-use) if a request on that connection returns a specific HTTP status code.

I've implemented a custom `http.RoundTripper`, which wraps an `http.Transport`, and can inspect the response status code. However, I can't seem to find a way to prevent the `http.Transport` from re-using that connection, without *also* preventing it from re-using any other connection.

Is this possible using the `net/http` package? If not, any suggested workaround for accomplishing this?

My current code looks something like this:

```
type MyTransport struct {
  transport *http.Transport
}

func (mt *MyTransport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
  resp, err := tt.transport.RoundTrip(req)
  if err != nil {
    return resp, err
  }
  
  if resp.StatusCode == 567 {
    // HERE:
    // Do something to prevent re-use of this connection
  }

  return resp, err
}
```

Comment: Can you use the `Close bool` field of the [`Request`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request) struct, that is, set it to `true`? I haven't tried it, but it sounds like the right tool for the job.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know whether the connection should be closed until after I get the response, since that decision is based on the response code, so I can't set that bool in the request.